# Shell - Delete only specific duplicates stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sed, duplicates

I'm trying to delete all lines with repeating path from the file.

**myfile.txt**

```
one two three four $HOME/mydir1/mydir2 six seven
one two three four $HOME/mydir1/mydir2 six seven
one two three four $HOME/mydir3/mydir4 six seven
```

The path is stored in a `$get_path` variable which I compare to the `$current_dir`.

```
file=myfile.txt
current_dir=$(pwd | sed "s|/home/$(whoami)|\$HOME|")
get_path=$(awk '{ print $5; exit }' $file)
```

If paths are similar I want them to be deleted from the file:

```
if [ "$get_path" == "$current_dir" ]; then
    sed -i "/$current_dir/d" $file
else
    echo "Else"
fi
```

Yet the `sed` gives me this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command
```

I don't want to use `uniq`/`sort` because it will require me to create temporary files. Plus the file I'm modifying may contain duplicate strings that I don't want to erase.

Comment: `sed` is using forward slashes (`/`) as the command/pattern delimiter, but the variable (`$current_dir`) also contains forward slashes as part of the data; in this situation `sed` attempts to process the variable's forward slashes as additional delimiters which in turn leads to syntax issues; the easy fix is to use a different character as the command/pattern delimiter => pick a character that you know does not exist in the data, eg, `|` => `sed -i "|$current_dir|d" $file`

Comment: You are using sed inside a shell conditional inside a script, and the whole isn't working. Try sed without the script; get that working before you try to wrap a script around it.

Comment: @markp-fuso after changing the sed command to yours, I've got another error: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'

Comment: *arg* ... my bad; the pipe also has special meaning so to signal the pipe will be the new delimiter you need to escape the first instance of the pipe, eg, `sed -i "\|$current_dir|d" $file`

Comment: @markp-fuso I've just stumbled upon the same answer trying to fix this. Now it works. Thank you!